# PostgreSQL V9.4 - Logical Decoding - SQL interface: Starting at a specific LSN?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I use PostgreSQL Logical Decoding functionality for retrieving WAL contents:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_create_logical_replication_slot(...)
SELECT * FROM pg_logical_slot_get_changes('<my_slot>', NULL, NULL);
```

These calls are implemented in the SQL interface within a "C" / ODBC 
programming framework.

This works very nice for me.
Data records are fetched one by one in a row - as expected.

Yet - there are certain cases where I need to re-position the slot flow 
to a past LSN.
The Logical Decoding REPLICATION interface provides means for achieving that.
For example the PG_RECVLOGICAL program introduces a "--startpos=X/Y" option 
that works as I expect.

Is there an equivalent option in the "SQL" interface?
I guess that both interfaces share much in common.
So - I went through the documentation and did not manage to find any equivalent 
option in the SQL interface.
For now - the SQL interface moves forward only and cannot retract back to a 
past LSN.
Did I miss something here?
Does any body have any clue or experience with that?

Kindest regards

Hillel.

Answer (score 0):

According to the replication SQL function docs it doesn't look possible :-(

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-REPLICATION